# Calling a Method From a String With the Method's Name in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

How can I do what they are talking about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python), but in Ruby?

How would you do the function on an object? and how would you do a global function (see jetxee's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python/834451#834451) on the post mentioned)?

**EXAMPLE CODE:**

```
event_name = "load"

def load()
  puts "load() function was executed."
end

def row_changed()
  puts "row_changed() function was executed."
end 

#something here to see that event_name = "load" and run load()
```

**UPDATE:**
How do you get to the global methods? or my global functions?

I tried this additional line

```
puts methods
```

and load and row_change where not listed.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

To call functions directly on an object

```
a = [2, 2, 3]
a.send("length")
# or
a.public_send("length")
```

which returns 3 as expected

or for a module function

```
FileUtils.send('pwd')
# or
FileUtils.public_send(:pwd)
```

and a locally defined method

```
def load()
    puts "load() function was executed."
end

send('load')
# or
public_send('load')
```

Documentation:

- [`Object#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send)
- [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send)

Comment: +1 That works. This may be a dumb follow up ... but how come I can't find the word send in the Ruby source at - C:\ruby\lib\ruby\1.8\fileutils.rb? Thought I would find the send function in there.

Comment: I was curious to what it was doing under the hood.

Comment: It's defined on object - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000332 I picked a random function for interest value.

Comment: Interesting because before I read your answer twice, and fully grok'd it I ran the FileUtils.send("load") and it ran my function. so if I understand this correctly by creating functions in "global" am I adding the methods onto the root object? or not?

Comment: Good on you for looking stuff up in the source! :)

Comment: I think they are being created as private method on the root object so global method might not be the best name for them

Comment: @Tyndall: Maybe it would be helpful not to think of them as functions. The only true functions in Ruby are created like `lambda {|x| x+1}`. Everything else is a method of some object. When you open an empty Ruby file and type `def foo(bar)`, you are defining a private method of the class Object. It will be available everywhere (since everything is an Object), but more specific classes are free to override it as well.

Comment: @tyndall, even lambda isn't really a function, it creates a Proc object. There was discussion about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933390/getting-ruby-function-object-itself

Comment: What if I need to pass parameters to the `load` function? How to do?

Comment: until (a = gets.chomp) =~ /(?:ex|qu)it/i
  send(a)
end

Comment: Also you can pass an argument object.send(:method, arg)

Answer (score 44):

### Three Ways: `send` / `call` / `eval` - and their Benchmarks

Typical invocation (for reference):

```
s= "hi man"
s.length #=> 6
```

#### Using `send`

```
s.send(:length) #=> 6
```

#### Using `call`

```
method_object = s.method(:length) 
p method_object.call #=> 6
```

#### Using `eval`

```
eval "s.length" #=> 6
```

### Benchmarks

```
require "benchmark" 
test = "hi man" 
m = test.method(:length) 
n = 100000 
Benchmark.bmbm {|x| 
  x.report("call") { n.times { m.call } } 
  x.report("send") { n.times { test.send(:length) } } 
  x.report("eval") { n.times { eval "test.length" } } 
}
```

> ...as you can see, instantiating a method object is the fastest dynamic way in calling a method, also notice how slow using eval is.

```
#######################################
#####   The results
#######################################
#Rehearsal ----------------------------------------
#call   0.050000   0.020000   0.070000 (  0.077915)
#send   0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.086071)
#eval   0.360000   0.040000   0.400000 (  0.405647)
#------------------------------- total: 0.550000sec

#          user     system      total        real
#call   0.050000   0.020000   0.070000 (  0.072041)
#send   0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.077674)
#eval   0.370000   0.020000   0.390000 (  0.399442)
```

Credit goes to this [blog post](http://blog.khd.me/ruby/ruby-dynamic-method-calling/) which elaborates a bit more on the three methods and also shows how to check if the methods exist.

Comment: I was just finding this, and I noticed something that wasn't covered. What would I do if I wanted to do `Class.send("classVariable") = 5`? That throws an error. Is there any way around that? The same thing is true for using `Class.method("classVariable").call() = 5`

Comment: if you want to send some argument with send call use something like this
ClassName.send("method_name", arg1, arg2)

Comment: Shouldn't your benchmark for `call` include instantiating the method object (`m.test.method(:length)`) to accurately represent it's true time? When using `call` you're _likely_ going to instantiate the method object every time.

Comment: Blog post link is dead, btw.

Answer (score 34):

Use this:

```
> a = "my_string"
> meth = a.method("size")
> meth.call() # call the size method
=> 9
```

Simple, right?

As for the *global*, I think the Ruby way would be to search it using the `methods` method.

Comment: meth = a.method? isn't this call the function already? what if the method returns something?

Comment: FYI for when the method doesn't exist: `"my_string".method('blah') #=> NameError: undefined method `blah' for class `String'`

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would setup a hash to function references and then use the string as an index to the hash. You then call the function reference with it's parameters. This has the advantage of not allowing the wrong string to call something you don't want to call. The other way is to basically [`eval`](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5188) the string. Do not do this.

PS don't be lazy and actually type out your whole question, instead of linking to something.

Comment: Sorry. I'll copy some of the wording and translate to make it Ruby specific. +1