# Rails - variable as part of method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, dynamic, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling a Function From a String With the Function's Name in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407451/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-ruby)

I want to do something like this:

```
  def self.greater_than(col_str='events')
    self."#{col_str}"_greater_than(30) # search logic scope method
  end
```

How can I get this to call properly?  I'm guessing the syntax is probably similar to creating a dynamic method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try using [`send`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Object.html#method-i-send)

```
send("#{col_str}_greater_than".to_sym, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def self.greater_than(col_str='events')
  self.send("#{col_str}_greater_than", 30) # search logic scope method
end
```